# Solutions not working for 'Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp' error with datetime in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, error-handling

Using python and pandas, after importing data, a date column defaults to the object datatype, so in trying to convert it to datetime, I get the error 'OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp'. Having searched previous questions with the same error message, my issue is not being resolved. All my dates are in between 2021-01-01 and 2022-12-31 in a pandas column. All data has the format yyyy-mm-dd i.e. no time.

Giving both the time range (2021-22) and time is not included in the date, I am not sure why this error is arising. I don't want to use the workaround:
`column_name = pd.to_datetime(column_name, errors = 'coerce')`
as I need to preserve all my dates, and besides, my data is within the permitted range.

Comment: Can you share an example of the original values that have been coerced to `NaN` by `pd.to_datetime` ?

Comment: Actually, I just applied `errors = 'coerce' ` and it's resolved it for me. I have to be honest I don't understand _why_ ...as it hasn't actually changed any values.

Comment: This is not what you say in your question : _I don't want to use the workaround as I need to preserve all my dates_.

Comment: That's correct - I didn't want to apply the workaround as I assumed it would change some  of the dates (if it doesn't change anything, how can it resolve the error?). But when you prompted me, I applied it anyway and the issue was resolved.